# Nginx remove Subdirectory path on Reverseproxy

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to map mydomain.com/api/ to port 9292 on my Spring application, which generally works, but I need the api/ removed from the proxy url.
I know, that I could add /api/ as context path to the Spring application, that is not an option.

**Nginx Conf:**

```
location /api/ {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

          proxy_connect_timeout 1d;
          proxy_send_timeout 1d;
          proxy_read_timeout 1d;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
```

Comment: Use: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/;`

Comment: @RichardSmith This actually worked! Nice and easy fix. Do you want to write an answer saying just that?